# UWP NavigationView Reseting Extend Into Title Bar Setting

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm creating a UWP app with a NavigationView that extends into the titlebar. My problem is that at startup, the NavView is in the correct position:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7NQm.jpg

But then after any window size change or on collapse of the NavView it resets to this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWDdk.jpg

Here's my NavigationView, and I'm populating the NavViewItems programmatically. I'm also setting the titlebar to the bottom grid element in the XAML.

```
<Grid>
    <NavigationView x:Name="navView"
                    AlwaysShowHeader="False"
                    Loaded="navView_Loaded"
                    ItemInvoked="navView_ItemInvoked"
                    BackRequested="navView_BackRequested"
                    Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlAcrylicElementBrush}"
                    >
        <NavigationView.AutoSuggestBox>
            <AutoSuggestBox QueryIcon="Find"
                            x:Name="navSearch"
                            TextChanged="navSearch_TextChanged"
                            QuerySubmitted="navSearch_QuerySubmitted"
                            PlaceholderText="Search Documents"
                            />
        </NavigationView.AutoSuggestBox>
        <Frame x:Name="navFrame"/>
    </NavigationView>
    <Grid x:Name="titleBarGrid" Background="Transparent" Margin="50, 0, 150, 0" Height="44" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

</Grid>
```

Comment: I fixed it. I copied the XAML template and changed the RowDefinition (Height = 0) for that spacer.